# C++ wrong output for little numbers for function (1-exp(-x))/x

Tags: c++, numbers

I need to find function (1-exp(-x))/x values from 10^-30 to 10^9. But for very small numbers the output is 0 but it should be 1. X is correct but there're some issues with fx, and i've not idea how to solve it.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    double fx ,x;
    x=pow(10.0L,-30);

    std::cout<<"fx\t\t\t\t"<<"x\t\t"<<std::endl;
    for(double i=0;x<pow(10,9);i+=0.01)
    {
        std::setprecision(20);
        x=pow(10.0L,-30+i);
        fx =(double)((1-exp(-pow(10,-30+i)))/pow(10,-30+i));
        std::cout<<x<<"\t\t\t\t\t"<<fx<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

My expected Output is:
for x ==10^-30 fx==1

But realoutput is:
for x ==10^-30 fx==0

Comment: what are "some issues" ? Please include actual and expected output in the question

Comment: in my opinion precision is incorrect: for x as 10^-30 the correct output should be 1 but is 0

Comment: You column headers are in `fx, x` order, but your output is in `x, fx` order...

Comment: btw your loop conditions looks odd, `x<pow(10,9);`. It invokes undefined behavior when you compare `x` uninitialized on the first iteration. You should fix that before any other issues with the code can be discussed

Comment: it doesn't matter, I look at the values

Comment: sorry, when I said please incldue them in the question, I meant that. What looks obvious to you may not be obvious to others, and the way to prevent misunderstanding is to be precise about what you expect vs what the code does

Comment: "it doesn't matter, I look at the values " yes it does matter. When your code has undefinded behavior then any output can appear on your screen or not

Comment: `x` is assigned a value before the loop starts.

Comment: @dreamlax ups. My bad ;)

Comment: "it doesn't matter, I look at the values " when i wrote this sentence I thought about 'You column headers are in fx, x order, but your output is in x, fx order..'

Comment: `f( 10^-30)` is close to 0, not 1: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%28x%29+%3D+%281+-+exp%28+-x%29+%29+%2F+x%2C+x+%3D+10%5E-30%2C+f%28x%29 (click `approximate form`), not clear why you expect a 1

Comment: I know it, and my question is how to correct it so that the rounding works

Comment: you say output is `0`, correct result is `0`. Whats the issue?

Comment: idon't think so https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281+-+exp%28+-%2810%5E-30%29+%29%29+%2F+%2810%5E-30%29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right that `fx` should be equal to about 1 for small `x`.
The issue is that `double` has a finite precision. Its relative error is much higher than `10^{-30}`.

A mantissa of at leat 100 bits would be needed.

This is illustrated by the following relation:

```
(1 - (1-x)) = 0
```

for very small `x`. See the code hereafter.

In other words, because of rounding  errors, the addition is no longer associative.

A workaround is to use a different formula for very small `x`, for example less than `10^{10}` in absolute value.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    double fx ,x;
    x = pow(10.0L,-30);
    std::setprecision(20);
    
    fx = (1.0 - exp(-x)) / x;
    std::cout << x << "\t" << fx << std::endl;
    
    fx = (1.0 - (1.0 - x))/x;
    std::cout << x << "\t" << fx << std::endl;

//  for very small x: 
    fx = 1 - x/2 + (x*x)/6;
    std::cout << x << "\t" << fx << std::endl;
}
```

**Output:**

```
1e-30   0
1e-30   0
1e-30   1
```